# Overwrites collection item's properties back to old data on SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, change-tracking

I'm currently developing an MVVM app using a Model-Designer based code-first design. So far I've been able to get all the basic CRUD operations working on single entities, however I can't seem to change the properties of collection objects at all using `SaveChanges()` - I've used an SQL profiler to see that it's attempting to UPDATE with the old value, and a step right after `SaveChanges()`  my changes get reverted to their old values!

**Some other info:**

- my `dbContext` is loaded using DI from PRISM/Unity and kept as a Unit-of-Work for a "details" page the user will edit and then save.
- My WPF UI is bound correctly and can modify the changes on an object-level.
- I can successfully use `Add()` to insert entities.
- I've verified the entity state of the entity in the child collection is Modified both by setting it and simplify debugging.
- I've attempted to manually `Attach()` and `AddOrUpdate()` on any or all items.
- I've turned off all Lazy Loading and instead manually included all collections.
- I've manually set the `Entry()` properties of `IsModified` and CurrentValue to their desired settings.
- I've tried binding my VM properties to their data by either 
  `dbContext.Classes.Local.ToBindingList()` or `new ObservableCollection<Class>(Entity.Property)`.

Is there anything that I could be missing here? Here's one attempt I've tried:
    // Assigning an Index object that contains relationships
    Index = await _model.PersonIndexes.Include(i => i.PersonAddresses).FirstAsync(i => i.Id == IndexId);

```
// Grabbing a filtered set of Addresses based on their data
var query = Index.PersonAddresses.Where(e => e.Condition == true );
Addresses = new ObservableCollection<PersonAddress>(await query.ToListAsync());

// Ensure state is tracked (I've tried with and without all  combinations of these)
foreach (PersonAddress addr in Addresses)
{
     //_model.PersonAddresses.AddOrUpdate(a => a.Id, addr);
     if (addr.PendingRemoval)
     {
           _model.PersonAddresses.Attach(addr);
           _model.Entry(addr).Property(a => a.PendingRemoval).CurrentValue = true;
           _model.Entry(addr).Property(a => a.PendingRemoval).IsModified = true;
      }
}

// Saving (after this line the properties of the entities in the related collection get reverted to their old values - i.e. if I change a phone number in the UI, the save below will replace the new values with the previous number.
await _model.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: You say you see it *attempting* to run SQL command to update the data.  Does it *actually* change values in the database?  If you see it running what looks like correct SQL, then you have done everything correctly as far as using EF to update the data.  Either there is a problem on the DB side, or data is being read back incorrectly.

Comment: `Is there anything that I could be missing here?` Yes. Code. Code is missing here. Or a crystal ball.

Comment: @BradleyUffner No database changes, and the SQL itself has an incorrect value. I think this points to something with the dbContext or my VM not being correct.

Comment: @LocEngineer Added one now, I can go back and try to find other attempts too if this one isn't clear enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this was an unfortunate error of configuration and a bad coincidence:

1) Check your models and server schema to ensure they are in sync (especially if using generated code from EF). In my case they were not, which lead to...

2) `SaveChanges()` was overwriting my properties in question because I had not noticed they were incorrectly set to have their `StoredGeneratorPattern` set to `Computed` in my model code. This caused the changed values to be ignored and overwritten.

3) The test case surrounding this had only implemented the same properties that were marked incorrectly, making it *appear* that all changes were being reverted - causing the confusion on where the problem code actually was. If another column had been modified and watched along with the others, this might have been caught sooner.